# Python Multiprocessing Processes seem to share objects also the should

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, shared-memory

In my multiprocessing code several workers for parallel processing.

The workers should only be communicating through a request_queue and a shared value with lock.

But it seems right now that because of "forking" when starting e.g. worker #4 and #5 share the same dictionary document. Which I found out using id(document) to see the memory address.

Due to storing the document in a mongodb, whose driver is writting back the _id to the document, strange errors appear.

**It has to be ensured that every worker is completly isolated expected the queue and the shared value, and I don't know how right now.**

The workers are started with:

```
for i in range(workers):
    Worker( request_queue,i,val, lock ).start()

class Worker(Process):
 def __init__(self, queue,ident,val,lock):
    super(Worker, self).__init__()

    self.queue= queue
    self.idstr= str(ident)
    self.val = val
    self.lock = lock
    dbconn = dbconnector.DBConnector()
    self.mongoconnection = dbconn.getMongoConnection()
    self.flagController = FlagController()
    print "Ident" + self.idstr

 def run(self):
    print 'Worker started'
    # do some initialization here

    print 'Worker Loop!'
    #time.sleep(5)
    try:
        for data in iter( self.queue.get, None ):
            mid = data["_id"]
            print "#" + self.idstr + " :  Mongoid " + str(mid)
            #time.sleep(5)
            try:

            timestamp = time.time()


            document = {"rawdata": data,
                                            "c": {
                                            "quelle": "t",
                                            "timestamp": mid.generation_time,
                                            "query" :  data["query"]                            
                                            }
                                            }

                    self.mongoconnection.insert("productive","input",document)
```

**Update**
I know tried to pass in a new document via the Constructor and use it inside the Worker via self.document, but that sadly doesn't help.

Comment: I think you have a cut/paste problem - I assume 'def run' should be part of the Worker class?

Comment: The workers don't share the same document. They may have the same id, but they are different processes and it just so happens that since the processes are all forked from the same place and are doing the same thing, they tend to allocate document at the same time. The id is only unique per process and for the lifetime of a single object. id is a horrible thing to use as a unique id in a database.

Comment: yes the run methods belgons to the worker

you are right with the id and that it is only unique per process, still the behavior is very strange and it looks like they are sharing the same document memory space.

This is a very good read http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2010/python-multiprocessing-linux-windows/

Comment: okay, i'm not a mongodb expert, but I think you want to remove whatever _id is in the doc when you get it `del data["_id"]` and either let mongo create a new one or create one yourself. But that's assuming that you don't want to honor what the parent process thats queueing this stuff up put into it.

Comment: the python mongodb driver has a bad side effect when you insert a document after the insert there will be document["_id"] = "xxx", but maybe we found the bug now it was probably our mongoconnection middleware

Answer (score 0):

One way of ensuring that each worker thread is isolated would be to give each one its own instance variable for the document. I.e. referencing document with self.document.

Comment: In the example, `document` is a local variable inside the run method. Making it self.document doesn't make it more isolated.

Comment: yep that is what i sadly also figured out, i also tried to pass in a new document via the constructor, which doesn't helper either